# Nokogiri extract object that is not wrapped in tags

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm loading regulations to a database and putting them in a tree hierarchy.  When the XML Im scraping is set up as below, it is trivial to scrape it:

```xml
<CHAPTER>
  <PART>
    <SUBPART>
      <SECTION>
        <HD>Section Title</HD>
      </SECTION>
      <SECTION> ... </SECTION>
      <APPENDIX>
        <HD>Appendix Title</HD>
        <P>Appendix content...</P>
        <FOO>More content in unexpected tags</FOO>
      </APPENDIX>
    </SUBPART>
    <SUBPART> ... </SUBPART>
  </PART>
</CHAPTER>
```

Since I have to know what the parent ID is, I do something along this line:

```ruby
parent_id = 1

doc.xpath("//chapter/part/subpart").each do |subpart| 
  title = subpart.xpath("hd").first.text

  # add is a method that creates object and saves it to database, returning its id
  id = add(title,'SUBPART',parent_id)

  subpart.xpath('section').each do |section|
    title = section.xpath('hd').first.text
    add(title,'SECTION',id)
  end

  subpart.xpath('appendix').each do |app|
    title = section.xpath('hd').first.text
    content = app.to_s
    add(title,'APPENDIX',id,content) #content is an optional input
  end
end
```

However, the XML is not always set up in such a logical way.  Sometimes, the appendices are not wrapped in  tags :(

When this is the case, the XML looks like this:

```xml
<EXTRACT>
  <HD SOURCE="HD1">Appendix A to § 1926.60—Substance Data Sheet, for 4-4′ Methylenedianiline</HD>
  <NOTE>
    <HD SOURCE="HED">Note:</HD>
    <P>The requirements applicable to construction work under this   appendix A are identical to those set forth in appendix A to § 1910.1050 of this chapter.</P>
  </NOTE>
  <HD SOURCE="HD1">Appendix B to § 1926.60—Substance Technical Guidelines, MDA</HD>
  <NOTE>
    <HD SOURCE="HED">Note:</HD>
    <P>The requirements applicable to construction work under this appendix B are identical to those set forth in appendix B to § 1910.1050 of this chapter.</P>
  </NOTE>
  <HD SOURCE="HD1">Appendix C to § 1926.60—Medical Surveillance Guidelines for MDA</HD>
  <NOTE>
    <HD SOURCE="HED">Note:</HD>
    <P>The requirements applicable to construction work under this appendix C are identical to those set forth in appendix C to § 1910.1050 of this chapter.</P>
  </NOTE>
  <HD SOURCE="HD1">Appendix D to § 1926.60—Sampling and Analytical Methods for MDA Monitoring and Measurement Procedures</HD>
  <NOTE>
    <HD SOURCE="HED">Note:</HD>
    <P>The requirements applicable to construction work under this appendix D are identical to those set forth in appendix D to § 1910.1050 of this chapter.</P>
  </NOTE>
</EXTRACT>
<CITA>
[57 FR 35681, Aug. 10, 1992, as amended at 57 FR 49649, Nov. 3, 1992; 61 FR 5510, Feb. 13, 1996; 61 FR 31431, June 20, 1996; 63 FR 1296, Jan. 8, 1998; 69 FR 70373, Dec. 6, 2004; 70 FR 1143, Jan. 5, 2005; 71 FR 16674, Apr. 3, 2006; 71 FR 50191, Aug. 24, 2006; 73 FR 75588, Dec. 12, 2008; 76 FR 33611, June 8, 2011; 77 FR 17889, Mar. 26, 2012]
</CITA>
```

The only way I can think of extracting these appendices is to iterate through the `<EXTRACT>` node and check the tags to see if its name is "HD" and "Appendix" is in the text.  Then save everything after until I hit the next `<HD>` with "Appendix" in the text.

Feels like a pretty clunky solution.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yeah, thats pretty much one can do for given XML